# enc28j60 with arduino and local web service

Tags: arduino

please help

i am trying to use arduino Pro mini with ENC28j60 to get data from my local web service

the URL i used to get the data is (http://192.168.1.5:801/m/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?tag=01)

when i use this URL in browser it return this result

peter danile,1234567

with arduino

i use this code but i can't get a result

```
// Demo using DHCP and DNS to perform a web client request.
// 2011-06-08 <jc@wippler.nl> http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

#include <EtherCard.h>

// ethernet interface mac address, must be unique on the LAN
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer;

const char website[] PROGMEM = "192.168.1.5";
//char website[] PROGMEM = "google.com";

// called when the client request is complete
static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
 Serial.println(">>>");
 Ethernet::buffer[off+300] = 0;
 Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off);
 Serial.println("...");
}

void setup () {
 Serial.begin(57600);
 Serial.println("\n[webClient]");

 if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac) == 0) 
   Serial.println( "Failed to access Ethernet controller");
 if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
   Serial.println("DHCP failed");

 ether.printIp("IP:  ", ether.myip);
 ether.printIp("GW:  ", ether.gwip);  
 ether.printIp("DNS: ", ether.dnsip);  

 if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
   Serial.println("DNS failed");

 ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);
}

void loop () {
 ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

 if (millis() > timer) {
   timer = millis() + 5000;
   Serial.println();
   Serial.println(PSTR("/m/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?"));
   Serial.print("<<< REQ ");
   ether.hisport = 801;//to access  local host
   ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/m/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld?"), "tag=01", website, my_callback);
 }
}
```

Comment: You're doing a DNS lookup on an ipaddress.

Comment: ok what should i do , did you have any examples . Thanks